# can you configure a block producer url permanently with cleos?

Tags: cleos, mainnet, network

I'd like to know if there's a config option instead of entering the url parameter for mainnet nodes every time, or what's the best option for convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following entry to config.ini.
p2p-peer-address = mainnet.eoscalgary.io:80

You can see a number of configuration examples at the link below.
https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet/blob/master/config.ini

You can see the url address of the mainnet and BP at the link below.
https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet/blob/master/config.ini